# Getting max dimensions for an image

Tags: actionscript-3, math

I'm working with a maximum constraint on dimensions of bitmapdata in as3. I'm trying to find the maximum width and height that conform to the constraints below and also maintain my aspect ratio of my image as it currently stands. My image is 2980 x 3220 (width x height).

Bitmapdata constraints:
In AIR 1.5 and Flash Player 10, **the maximum size for a BitmapData object is 8,191 pixels in width or height**, and the total number of pixels cannot exceed **16,777,215 pixels**. (So, if a BitmapData object is 8,191 pixels wide, it can only be 2,048 pixels high.)

If you could let me know how you arrived at your answer that would be awesome too

Edit:
find values for width and height where width / height = ratio = 0.9254658385
AND
width * height = some number as close to, but not exceeding max pixels (16,777,215)

Comment: 16,777,215/8191=2,048

Comment: 2980 / 3220 != 2048 / 8191 -> it must maintain the aspect ratio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2980*3220=9595600. Now, if we divide 16777216 by this number, we'll receive how much more pixels can your bitmap have while remaining in the constraints = 1.7484. To maintain aspect ratio, you have to increase both width and height by the same percentage, thus we need to take a square root of this = 1.3222 (this is rounded down at 4th digit). Multiply your dimension by this, receive 3940*4257, totaling 16772580 pixels, and both width and height are less than 8192.

So, your image can have at most 3940 width and 4257 height.